# Using composite design pattern with Icon interface

Tags: java, design-patterns, composite

I am trying to use a composite design pattern to display icons on a JPanel. I have a composite class which extends Icon and has an ArrayList that holds a custom class implementing Icon and extending ImageIcon. I want to call the composites paintIcon() method and loop through the ArrayList, and paint all the contained Icons. I can paint an Icon to the screen if I simply call an ImageIcon and add it to my panel. I don't understand why the paintIcon() called from the CompositeIcon isn't working. The following method loops the ArrayList, but doesn't seem to print from the screen. when setIcon() is called in the GUI, shouldn't this paint onto the JPanel?

```
@Override
public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int i, int i1) {
    for(int j = 0; j < icons.size(); j++){
        icons.get(j).paintIcon(c, g, listX.get(j), listY.get(j));
    }
}
```

So far I have a tester:

```
public class Display extends JFrame {


public CompositeIcons icons = new CompositeIcons();



public Display() throws MalformedURLException{
    super();

    this.setTitle("Composite Pattern");
    this.setSize(600, 600);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //this.setResizable(false);
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("discover.png");
    IconOne iconOne = new IconOne("discover.png");    

    icons.addIcon(iconOne, 10, 10);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setIcon(icons);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1, true));
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    this.add(panel);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

and a composite class:

```
public class CompositeIcons implements Icon {

private ArrayList<Icon> icons = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList<Integer> listX = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList<Integer> listY = new ArrayList();



public void addIcon(Icon icon, int x, int y){
    icons.add(icon);
    listX.add(x);
    listY.add(y);
}




@Override
public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int i, int i1) {
    for(int j = 0; j < icons.size(); j++){
        icons.get(j).paintIcon(c, g, listX.get(j), listY.get(j));
    }
}

@Override
public int getIconWidth() {
    return 40;
}

@Override
public int getIconHeight() {
    return 40;
}

}
```

and a sample custom Icon class:

```
public class IconOne extends ImageIcon implements Icon {

ImageIcon image;
int x, y;



public IconOne(String icon){
    super(icon);

}





@Override
public void paintIcon(Component cmpnt, Graphics grphcs, int i, int i1) {

}

@Override
public int getIconWidth() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public int getIconHeight() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

Comment: The last two arguments of paintIcon are the x and y specifying where to draw the icon on the component. You're just ignoring them. You should propagate them correctly, something like `icons.get(j).paintIcon(c, g, x+listX.get(j), y+listY.get(j));`. Also the paintIcon() method in IconOne is empty, so there's no chance of it displaying anything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the paintIcon method from IconOne. The class already extends ImageIcon which implements it.